# Why datanode is not running?

Tags: java, hadoop, uri, hdfs

After I format the namenode, ./stop-all.sh and then ./start-all.sh I get this in the log:

```
2015-11-29 18:29:28,395 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ResourceMonitorLogger: File /user/hadoop/monitoring/anmol-vm1-new_resources.csv could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1441)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2010)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1561)
```

Also here's what I see in the jps:

```
24765 NameNode
26155 SecondaryNameNode
28223 Jps
26472 NodeManager
26316 ResourceManager

Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
```